# How to setOnClick Listerner for a Button in android Studio 4.1

Tags: android, kotlin

Thank You All!

I am new to Android and Kotlin. Before I upgraded to Android Studio 4.1, I used the following code,

```
button1.setOnClickListener {
        textView.text = "Button 1 Tapped!"
}
```

and all was ok.
After Upgrading, the above code shows an error on button1, "unresolved reference:button1".

Please, help. how do i set onClickListener for a button in Android Studio 4.1.
I am using Kotlin.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before setting set `OnClickListener` you should find the view :

```
        val button1: Button = findViewById(R.id.button1)
        button1.setOnClickListener {...}
```

Comment: Thanks alot 30mb1. It works!  Before I went straight to setting onClickListerner without finding the the view. seems now that is a crucial part of it after the upgarde. Again thanks

Comment: you don't have to do this if you're using synthetic imports

Comment: tried 'import kotlinx.android.sythentic.main.home_activity' but not working. 'kotlinx' is in red with 'unresolved refernce'. Not sure how to use synthetic imports. I am trying to learn kotlin at home... Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: @ 30mb1.  After adding val button1: Button = findViewById(R.id.button1), the app crashed when running ain emulator and physical android device. Anything I am doing wrong?

Comment: I think I got it now. finding the view needs to be in the oncreate fun. Thanks my people

Comment: Kotlin Synthetic will be deprecated and remove in near future so do not use them.

Comment: Ok, Thanks Alot.

Answer (score 0):

```
lateinit var button1: Button
...
button1 = findViewById(R.Id.buttonId)
button.setOnClickListener{ }
```

or

```
val button1: Button? = null
...
button1 = findViewById(R.id.buttonId)
button1.setOnclickListener{ }
```

or

```
...
val button1: Button = findViewById(R.id.buttonId)
button1.setOnClickListener{ }
```